# need to update variables, main thread or different thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, swingworker

Sorry if the question sounds stupid, I haven't been programming for too long, so I have this kind o newbie questions...

I have a JFrame (JFrame form from netBeans) with some variables(arrayList, int...). After a process, this variables change. The process is an mySQL query through JCDB driver, some arrayList update with data, which I use to fill a Jtable... and so on...

At first (poor me) I made a SwingWorker. Through the SwingWorker constructor, I pass these variables (about 6 variables more or less), and use them to do the processing and fill the tables.

I thought I would be able to update the value of these variables in the overriden Done() method (poor me again), and not just the GUI components.

I learned many things with this failure:
1) even though I passed the variables through the constructor, that doesn't mean they get updated in the place they come from.
2) SwingWorker can only return 1 variable, and modify GUI components.

So, and this is my main point, how can I do what I was trying to do? I learned it can't be done with SwingWorker class but then, how can it be done?

I don't want to put the code in an mouse click event just like that, because it would block my EDT with no notification to the user about what's happening.

I though about doing something like this: place the code inside a mouse click event, and show a Dialog so the user knows that a process is taking place at the moment.

```
private void jButton_calcular_rutaMousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                                   
        // BOTON CALCULAR RUTA

        int index = jL_empGeo.getSelectedIndex();

        JOptionPane optionPane = new JOptionPane("Descargando ruta, espere por favor.", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, null, new Object[]{}, null);
        JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
        dialog.setTitle("Descarga");
        dialog.setModalityType(Dialog.DEFAULT_MODALITY_TYPE);

        dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);

        Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        dialog.setLocation(dim.width / 2 - dialog.getSize().width / 2, dim.height / 2 - dialog.getSize().height / 2);
        dialog.setContentPane(optionPane);

        dialog.pack();

        dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(this);

        dialog.setVisible(true);

        //
        // THE PROCESSING TAKES PLACE HERE
        //
        //
        // mySQL query
        //
        // update arrayLists and variables
        //
        // update GUI components
        //
        //

        dialog.setVisible(false);
    }
```

Would this make any sense? is there any way to do the processing in a different Thread and afterwards get the arrayLists and variables back into the main thread?

Thanks in advance for your help.

**EDIT**

SwingWorker class

```
package descargas;

import clases.Empleados;
import clases.InfoPuntoRuta;
import com.mysql.jdbc.Connection;
import com.mysql.jdbc.Statement;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import maps.java.Geocoding;
import maps.java.Route;
import maps.java.StaticMaps;

public class ActualizarRuta2 extends SwingWorker<Void, Void> {

    int index;
    ArrayList<Empleados> arrayEmpleados;
    ArrayList<InfoPuntoRuta> listaPuntosRuta;
    DefaultTableModel modeloTablaRutas;
    JDialog dialog;
    ArrayList<String> listaIntermedios;
    JLabel jLab_RutaMAP;
    ImageIcon icono;
    int origenInt;
    int destinoInt;
    int destinoMax;

    public ActualizarRuta2(int index, int origenInt, int destinoInt, int destinoMax, ArrayList<Empleados> arrayEmpleados, ArrayList<InfoPuntoRuta> listaPuntosRuta, DefaultTableModel modeloTablaRutas, JDialog dialog, JLabel jLab_RutaMAP) {
        this.index = index;
        this.arrayEmpleados = arrayEmpleados;
        this.listaPuntosRuta = listaPuntosRuta;
        this.modeloTablaRutas = modeloTablaRutas;
        this.dialog = dialog;
        this.jLab_RutaMAP = jLab_RutaMAP;
        this.origenInt = origenInt;
        this.destinoInt = destinoInt;
        this.destinoMax = destinoMax;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {

        listaIntermedios = new ArrayList<String>();

        // recogemos la fecha actual
        DateFormat formatoFecha = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        String dateMIN = formatoFecha.format(cal.getTime()) + " 00:00:01";
        String dateMAX = formatoFecha.format(cal.getTime()) + " 23:59:59";

        // GENERAR MAPA DE LA RUTA DEL DIA
        Connection conexion;
        conexion = conexiondb.ConexionDB.getConnection();
        if (conexion != null) {
            try {
                Statement st;
                ResultSet rs;

                st = (Statement) conexion.createStatement();
                rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * \n"
                        + "FROM position\n"
                        + "WHERE nombre =  '" + arrayEmpleados.get(index) + "'\n"
                        + "AND position_date BETWEEN '" + dateMIN + "' AND '" + dateMAX + "'\n"
                        + "ORDER BY position_date;");

                // vaciamos la lista
                //listaPuntosRuta.clear();
                //System.out.println(rs.);
                // rellenamos la lista
                rs.beforeFirst();

                while (rs.next()) {
                    InfoPuntoRuta punto = new InfoPuntoRuta(rs.getString("nombre"),
                            rs.getString("position_date"), rs.getDouble("latitud"),
                            rs.getDouble("longitud"));

                    Geocoding ObjGeocod = new Geocoding();
                    ArrayList<String> resultadoCI = ObjGeocod.getAddress(punto.getLatitud(), punto.getLongitud());
                    String direccion = resultadoCI.get(0);

                    punto.setDireccion(direccion);

                    listaIntermedios.add(direccion);
                    listaPuntosRuta.add(punto);
                }

                //
                // DESCARGAR MAPA RUTA
                //
                int posicionUltimo = (listaIntermedios.size()) - 1;
                String origen, destino;

                ArrayList<String> waypoints = new ArrayList<String>();
                if (listaIntermedios.size() < 10) {
                    origen = listaIntermedios.get(0);
                    destino = listaIntermedios.get(posicionUltimo);
                    for (int i = 1; i < posicionUltimo; i++) {
                        waypoints.add(listaIntermedios.get(i));
                    }
                } else {
                    origen = listaIntermedios.get(0);
                    destino = listaIntermedios.get(9);
                    for (int i = 1; i < 9; i++) {
                        waypoints.add(listaIntermedios.get(i));
                    }
                }

//                ArrayList<String> prueba = new ArrayList<String>();
//                prueba.add("coruña avenida finisterre 65");
//                prueba.add("coruña ronda de outeiro 125");
//                prueba.add("coruña avenida del ejercito 20");
                Route ObjRout = new Route();

                String[][] resultadoRuta = ObjRout.getRoute(origen, destino, waypoints, Boolean.TRUE, Route.mode.driving, Route.avoids.nothing);
                //String[][] resultadoRuta = ObjRout.getRoute("Madrid", "Barcelona", prueba, Boolean.TRUE, Route.mode.driving, Route.avoids.nothing);
//                String[][] resultadoRuta = ObjRout.getRoute("coruña virrey ossorio 25", "pla y cancela, 16, 15005 la coruña, españa", prueba, Boolean.TRUE, Route.mode.driving, Route.avoids.nothing);
                String polylinea = ObjRout.getGeneralPolyline();
                StaticMaps ObjStatMap = new StaticMaps();
                Image resultadoMapa = ObjStatMap.getStaticMapRoute(new Dimension(585, 405), 1, StaticMaps.Format.png, StaticMaps.Maptype.hybrid, polylinea);
                icono = new ImageIcon(resultadoMapa);

                // RELLENAR TABLA DETALLES DE LA RUTA
                modeloTablaRutas.setRowCount(0);

            } catch (SQLException | UnsupportedEncodingException | MalformedURLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ActualizarRuta2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } finally {
                try {
                    conexion.close();
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(ActualizarRuta2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void done() {

        dialog.dispose();

        // RELLENAR TABLA DETALLES DE LA RUTA
        for (InfoPuntoRuta p : listaPuntosRuta) {
            modeloTablaRutas.addRow(new Object[]{
                p.getNombre(), p.getFecha(), p.getDireccion()});
        }

        // ponemos la imagen de la ruta
        jLab_RutaMAP.setIcon(icono);

        //
        listaIntermedios.clear();

//        listaPuntosRuta.clear();
        origenInt = 0;
        destinoMax = listaPuntosRuta.size() - 1;
        if (destinoMax < 9) {
            destinoInt = destinoMax;
        } else {
            destinoInt = 9;
        }

    }

}
```

Mouse event where I call the SwingWorker

```
private void jButton_calcular_rutaMousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                                   
        // BOTON CALCULAR RUTA

        int index = jL_empGeo.getSelectedIndex();

        JOptionPane optionPane = new JOptionPane("Descargando ruta, espere por favor.", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, null, new Object[]{}, null);
        JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
        dialog.setTitle("Descarga");
        dialog.setModalityType(Dialog.DEFAULT_MODALITY_TYPE);

        dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);

        Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        dialog.setLocation(dim.width / 2 - dialog.getSize().width / 2, dim.height / 2 - dialog.getSize().height / 2);
        dialog.setContentPane(optionPane);

        dialog.pack();

        dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(this);

        listaPuntosRuta.clear();
        modeloTablaRutas.setRowCount(0);
        ActualizarRuta2 task = new ActualizarRuta2(index, origenInt, destinoInt, destinoMax, arrayEmpleados, listaPuntosRuta, modeloTablaRutas, dialog, jLab_RutaMAP);
        task.execute();

        dialog.setVisible(true);

    }
```

Comment: Would you mind including your (failed) SwingWorker example as well

Comment: Yes, it is included now :)

Comment: I think you're focusing too much on the properties and not enough on the fact that you're operating in a OO environment.  That is, you should be able to provide just enough information to the `SwingWorker` to do it's job and once complete, it should be able to supply the information you need to update yourself.  At the moment, the worker is trying to perform the query AND update the UI, it has cross purposes. @ThomasW hits at the basic idea you need to start with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there any way to do the processing in a different Thread and afterwards get the arrayLists and variables back into the main thread?

Yes, there is. You can (and probably should) start a new thread after `dialog.setVisible(true)` using

```
new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        getNewValues();
    }
}.start();
```

Once this job is done, from your "worker"-thread, you can invoke

```
EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //overwrite existing variables, update GUI elements, trigger repaints, etc.
        dialog.setVisible(false);
    }
};
```

However, you should always try to separate your data from your view. That means: You probably should not invoke those actions from your worker thread, but implement the [observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) to inform your GUI that the data has changed and to refresh itself.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick answer. I will try it tomorrow as it's very late in my country.

Comment: Good answer, a quick check of the docs confirms SwingWorker.done() in javax.swing.SwingWorker will automatically run in the EDT.. so less need for an explicit `invokeLater()`. It's good to be aware of how it works, though.

Comment: what would the getNewValues() method be? the swingWorker?

Comment: No. It would be the _content_ of the SwingWorker and would therefor replace it. I tend to keep my distance from tools like SwingWorker because anything called "Swing" may never touch my data. I'm a bit paranoid when it comes to separation of concerns between view and data ;)

Comment: If I start the thread after the `dialog.setVisible(true)`, the thread is never executed

Comment: if I put the `dialog.setVisible()` at the end of the event, the the thread does execute. BUT, the invokeLater isn't waiting for the thread to finish.

Comment: @jacho981 Both your observations confuse me. Especially the second one: The invokeLater should take place at the _end_ of your update method, meaning the last line of `getNewValues()` (or equivalently as last line of the Thread's `run()` method).

Comment: oooooooook, I placed the invokelater after the thread in the mouse click event, no at the end of the getNewValues. sometimes I loose my fight against English hehehe. thx!

Answer (score 2):

You need communication from your 'SwingWorker', back to the GUI. Java parameters are *pass by value* -- so therefore, you need some form of *value holder*.

Making a 'data bean' descending from Observable, is probably the simplest way.

```
public class QueryResults extends Observable {
    protected List<SomeItem> itemList;
    // getters and setters.
}
```

From your SwingWorker, you need to store the results & notify observers. Notification must be done on the event-dispatch thread, and javax.swing.SwingWorker provides built-in functionality to call SwingWorker.done() on the EDT.

I have used 'Void' types as a "result", since the data-holder already exists & we are just loading data into it. The UI should already be bound to (and observing) it. Something like this:

```
public class QueryWorker<Void,Void> extends SwingWorker {
    protected QueryResults holder;
    public QueryWorker (QueryResults holder) {
        this.holder = holder;  // keep the holder & put data into it.
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() {
        // run the query..
    }
    @Override
    protected void done() {
        holder.notifyObservers();
    }
}
```

This is a simplified example. It omits the possibility, for example, of the UI wanting to read the result-hodler (for display refresh) in the middle of loading. Your alternative there is to keep the *data bean* separate from the *observable reference* to the bean.